# Classic ASP equivalent of PHP's pack()

Tags: php, asp-classic

What is the equivalent function for PHP's [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function in Classic ASP ?

Comment: There is no equivalent function in Classic ASP. PHP being open source has had lots of support for Third party libraries over the years and lots of additions between versions, whereas Classic ASP never had that much ongoing development which put it at a disadvantage in my opinion. The only real way to add to Classic ASP is using COM components which are DLLs you register with the web server and access through Classic ASP via COM. There are some free ones but the good ones are usually licensed and will cost you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box there is no equivalent function in Classic ASP. You basically have a few options when it comes to implementing this functionality in Classic ASP, you can;

1. Use a COM component that mimics the functionality which includes using .NET assemblies that are exposed to COM.
2. Attempt to write the code yourself but with VBScript especially you will likely hit problems working with byte arrays etc.
3. Write your own COM component in a mainstream language like C++ or C# *(there are others I'm just not listing them all and unsure of there support for COM enabled DLLs)*.

Comment: Where can I find these COM components? Tried to search, but can't find any related.

Comment: @Raptor only one I can think of off the top of my head is [motobit.com - ASP file upload and ScriptUtilities (Binary data manipulation)](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/upload.asp). Also they provide some vanilla approaches to [binary manipulation between variant arrays and true byte arrays](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/), it's all a little heavy though and if I had to do this I'd try to use something like c# to write my own COM visible DLL that could do the heavy lifting for me.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it

Comment: I've used this in the past and it worked fine: https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8525&lngWId=4

Comment: @TimWilliams to my knowledge the OP is not after an upload solution, I just pointed him to that site because it deals with byte array manipulation. I have used something similar myself in the past, used to use FreeASPUpload until the site stopped working but still have heavily modified versions of the code floating around.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach to achieve this:

```
Dim key2, hexarr, binstr
key2 = "12 34 56 78 90 AB CD EF"
hexarr = Split(key2)
ReDim binarr(UBound(hexarr))

For i = 0 To UBound(hexarr)
  binarr(i) = Chr(CInt("&h" & hexarr(i)))
Next

binstr = Join(binarr, "")
```

where `key2` is the original secret padded by space every 2 characters.

The result is identical as PHP's `pack()`, though the other functions in Classic ASP are unable to read the `binstr` properly.